# How to implement "array type" grammar like typescript with pegjs?

Tags: javascript, grammar, pegjs

my problem is in the implementation of "array type" like typescript.

according to my grammar. In "array type" you can use "[]" after any type (eg string or int or even array again like int[][]).

this is simplified version of my grammar:

```
start = type

type = array / bool / string / int

string = "string"
int = "int"
bool = "bool"

// problem
array = t:type "[]" { return { kind: "array",type: t }}
```

the above code throw an syntax error:

Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: _When_ do you get the error? When the _grammar_ is parsed? When you try an parse something _with_ it? Some other time?

Comment: When i'm "writing" grammar. This is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar `type` can call `array`, `array` can call `type` again, and so on. You need to create a new type rule that contains `array` as last case so that it won't loop:

```
start = type

primitive = bool / string / int
type = primitive / array

string = "string"
int = "int"
bool = "bool"

array = t:type "[]" { return { kind: "array",type: t }}
```

Comment: Except that an array can be an array of arrays, so this doesn't work. The issue is how to create a recursive rule in pegjs.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Edited. It should work recursively now.